# Habitat Fragmentation Index calculation

Tags: qgis, vegetation-index, habitat-modeling, fragstats

What is the correct plugin/function to calculate a Habitat Fragmentation Index in QGIS (I use the 2.18 version) or FRAGSTAT starting from a vector layer?

I suppose that, first, I must convert the vector layer into a raster layer?

At the beginning, I was thinking about to use the Shannon Diversity Index, but I don't think that it's appropriate as it calculates the diversity in terms of habitats, but not the degree of habitat fragmentation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS.SE! I think your question needs to be clarified. ¶1 seems to be asking how to calculate habitat fragmentation using QGIS, while ¶3 seems to be asking the scientific question of which index or measure of habitat fragmentation to use. These are two very different question, and the second question is probably not appropriate GIS.SE. Can you please pick one, and expand somewhat on the question?

Comment: Dear Dr. Hachadoorian, thanks for your reply. My question is related to how to calculate a habitat fragmentation index using QGIS or FRAGSTAT. What is the correct plugin and or function that needs to be used? Many thanks.

Comment: Please keep in mind that there is no single metric for fragmentation per se. The process is inferred through a combination of metrics that are dependent on the specific system. To correctly do this you set up a hypothesis of what characteristics fragmentation and then test it with select metrics that measure said characteristics.

Comment: Dear Dr. Evans, thanks for the information. Based on your suggestions I looked on the net  where I found an interesting video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM9XfCArh1Y) explaining how landscape analysis should be performed using the "Lecos" plugin. Many thanks again.